# What's the difference between "doing my homework" and "to do my homework"?

Tags: difference, participles

Suddenly I got a question studying participle.

> 1. I spent too much time yesterday ***doing*** my homework.
> 2. I spent too much time yesterday ***to do*** my homework.

Is no.2 grammatically correct?
If so, what's the difference between the two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1: *I spent too much time yesterday doing my homework.*
>    2: *I spent too much time yesterday to do my homework.*

Technically speaking, #2 there is "valid" (if "awkward") - but it doesn't mean the same as #1, and would only make sense if we contrive some unusual context where the speaker spent an excessive amount of time *doing something else*, and was thus unable to do his homework (note that in the *first* version, the speaker is saying that the amount of time he spent doing homework was excessive).

For a "matched pair" where both alternatives more obviously make sense, consider...

> 3: *I lost too much money yesterday playing cards*
>    4: *I lost too much money yesterday to play cards*

...where #3 means the speaker *did* play cards (yesterday) - but he lost an excessive amount of money. But #4 means the speaker ***was unable to*** play cards (either yesterday, or perhaps earlier on the day of speaking) because he didn't have enough money (having lost so much yesterday - feasibly, but not necessarily, by playing cards).

Note that in #4 it's even possible the speaker still has plenty of money - but because he lost so much yesterday, he doesn't want to repeat the experience. In *that* interpretation, it's contextually almost certain that he lost the money playing cards - not by, for example, placing too much money on losing bets with a bookmaker, or even simply losing his wallet somehow.

---

In examples #2 and #4, ***to*** essentially has the sense of ***in order to*** - as in ***I withdrew some money from the cash machine to play cards***. But when the preceding clause includes ***too*** [much/many], this pragmatically implies *it wasn't/isn't possible* to perform the second action *(doing homework, playing cards)*, because of some kind of "excess" associated with the first activity.